# Acessing COM Interop from Python

Tags: c#, python, com, interop

I want to acess a COM interop functionality written in c# from Python. I have the following code written in c# which defines the COM interop functionality and is compiled as a .dll and registered using regasm.exe. This seems to work fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ComInteropDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// implementation of the method com interface
    /// </summary>
    [Guid("1C9E938A-9BF5-4A42-B795-A4AC2B1E7AC0")]
    [ProgId("Test.Test.ComInteropClass")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IComInteropClass))]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ComInteropClass : IComInteropClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Reads a text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text (as out parameter)</param>
        /// <returns>true if successful</returns>
        public bool ReadText(out string text)
        {
            text = "Hello from Com Interop";

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes a text to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        /// <returns>true if successful</returns>
        public bool WriteText(string text)
        {
            string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "ComInteropDemoOutput.txt");

            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I want to acess the COM interop functionality from python (client side), I try to use the comtypes library for that and I try to load the COM interop demo using the following code:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject

comobject = CreateObject("Test.Test.ComInteropClass")
```

Problem is, it throws an errors saying:
"AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.ComInteropDemo' has no attribute 'IComInteropClass'"

It seems I have to define the attribute IComInteropClass in the c# definition of the COM functionality, but I do not know how. Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I've got the same issue. did you found a solution?